# Can't login to jenkins after installation. It goes to login after installation instead of initialPassword page

Tags: docker, authentication, jenkins

I installed jenkins using docker

docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d --restart=on-failure -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v  jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts

Something happened I deleted the container and the image and reinstalled it but instead of showing me where I will enter the initialPassword it goes to login page

I have checked jenkins_home for the initialPassword but I cant find it

I am using macbook

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the initial password in the running container.

The path of the initialAdminPassword file is:-

**/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword**

Please check the screenshot FYR:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd3e9.png)